# Return void function with result of another void function?

Tags: go, idioms

I'm trying to come up with a very compact way of handling problems that may arise in HTTP requests for a REST API.

There are many conditions that I need to test for, and many potential error responses for the failure of any of these conditions.

I've gotten my handling flow down to something that looks similar to the following:

```
// Error is actually a method on some struct, so it's only relevant for demonstration purposes.
func Error(w http.ResponseWriter, status int, message string) {
  // Lots of stuff omitted
  w.WriteHeader(status)
  w.WriteJson(r)
}

func HandleSomething(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
  if someCondition != true {
    Error(w, 500, "Some error occurred!")
    return
  }
  if someOtherCondition != true {
    Error(w, 500, "Some other error occurred!")
    return
  }
  if yetAnotherCondition != true {
    Error(w, 500, "Yet another error occurred!")
    return
  }
  if andFinallyOneLastCondition != true {
    Error(w, 500, "One final error occurred!")
    return
  }
  // All good! Send back some real data.
  w.WriteJson(someObject)
}
```

Since there are often 5-10 conditions that I need to test for, and other errors that can arise during other operations, it would be nice to be able to compact it to the following:

```
func HandleSomething(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
  if someCondition != true {
    return Error(w, 500, "Some error occurred!")
  }
  if someOtherCondition != true {
    return Error(w, 500, "Some other error occurred!")
  }
  if yetAnotherCondition != true {
    return Error(w, 500, "Yet another error occurred!")
  }
  if andFinallyOneLastCondition != true {
    return Error(w, 500, "One final error occurred!")
  }
  // All good! Send back some real data.
  w.WriteJson(someObject)
}
```

However, the Go compiler doesn't like this.

It complains both that I'm trying to use the result of `Error()` as a value, and that I'm trying to return too many arguments. The exact error messages are:

```
foo.go:41: bar.Response.Error(400, "InvalidRequest", "Error decoding request") used as value
foo.go:41: too many arguments to return
```

But both `Error()` and `HandleSomething()` have the same return signature (e.g. they both return nothing), so shouldn't this work?

It's important that each `if` statement contains a `return`, because the function should be exited immediately. If `Error()` could somehow stop the execution of the calling function, that would also work for me. Sort of like `testing.FailNow()`, but I believe that relies on Goroutines.

*As an aside: I realize that these aren't really "void" functions, but couldn't think of a more appropriate name. Is there a proper name for functions that return nothing in Go?*

Comment: A function that returns nothing in go is just that. There's no name for it, because it's nothing special in itself.

Answer (score 0):

C++ allows this. It is very handy for templates.

But as you see Go does not. I am not sure of the exact steps, but this seems like something you could ask to be added to Go, perhaps it could make it in for 1.7.

As for a solution right now, perhaps you could return a unused `error`. Just return it as `nil` from your `Error` function.

Comment: The go language is pretty much done as you see it, and changes have an extremely high bar to be accepted. Making an exception to the language spec to essentially save a new line character isn't likely to be accepted.

Comment: @JimB: Go allows an empty return. It just doesn't allow returning the empty return from another function. This doesn't seem like a big change to me. Could at least try and see if the change could be done.

Comment: @DC_: A [return statement](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Return_statements) may contain 0 or more [expressions](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Expressions). An expression results in a *value* by definition. Also in the spec: "In a function without a result type, a "return" statement must not specify any result values". Even minor language changes may have unintended consequences that need to be maintained for the life of the language, and it could be a large price to pay to condense 2 lines into one (note that proposals like combining for+select to save a line have been rejected too)

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure but i would do it with the if-else fashion

```
func HandleSomething(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
  if someCondition != true {
    Error(w, 500, "Some error occurred!")
  } else if someOtherCondition != true {
    Error(w, 500, "Some other error occurred!")
  } else if yetAnotherCondition != true {
    Error(w, 500, "Yet another error occurred!")
  } else if andFinallyOneLastCondition != true {
    Error(w, 500, "One final error occurred!")
  } else {
    // All good! Send back some real data.
    w.WriteJson(someObject)
  }
}
```